# jQuery Filter List Effect

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to know what plugin is used for filter list @ http://www.kriesi.at/themes/angular/
you can see effect by click any of link (All/CSS/HTML/PSD/Video) to see effect Please let me know if it's not a jQuery plugin so how I can do this kind of effect thanks.

Regards,
Muhammad Asif

Comment: http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Answer (score 0):

They use Isotope JS. Check out more details at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/.